# How to scale the y-axis automatically to move down the line chart in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, scale, linechart

[image]

Hi all,
I have a chart (as shown above) which have a lot of empty space at the lower part. I want to scale my y-axis automatically so that I can move down my line chart. How should I do that? I'm fine with VBA but don't prefer to assign the macro in a button, preferably able to scale the chart automatically without pressing any button.
 Thank you.

Comment: Did you try recording a macro while setting the y-axis limits to "auto"?

Comment: The y-axis limits is "auto" by default